# Perl calling perl

Tags: bash, perl, permissions, chmod

I am having permission errors with perl.

A perl script is calling another one using a config file.
executeParsers.pl --> read config file --> call parser1.pl

Error is hapenning only when there are 2 lines in the config file.
*File : ssh.conf**

```
OBS,9 Cegetel,Altitude;sh ip int;shipint;parser1.pl
OBS,9 Cegetel,Altitude;sh int status;shintstatus;parser2.pl
```

*File : executeParsers.pl*

```
$DIR="/tech/gtr/scripts/osm/environnement_qualif/scan-rh2";

open(SSHCONFIG, "$DIR/bin/ssh.conf");
while (<SSHCONFIG>) {
    $ifname = (split)[0];
    my @status = split /;/;
    for (@status) {
            print ("$_ \n");
        }
    #@ligne = split(/;/, $_ );
    $listop = $status[0];
    $listcmd = $status[1];
    $fileprefix = $status[2];
    print "prefixe trouve $fileprefix \n";
    $parsername = $status[3];

    $tab=`find $DIR/working-dir -type f -name \"$fileprefix*\"`;
    print "j'ai trouve les fichiers suivant : $tab \n";
    @table = split(/\n/,$tab);

    for ($index = 0; $index <= $#table; $index++) {
        print "le fichier numero $index est : $table[$index]\n";
        $fichier = $table[$index];
        print "fichier traite : $fichier\n";
        system("/usr/bin/perl $DIR/parsers/$parsername $fichier");
    }
}
close (SSHCONFIG);
```

And file *parser1.pl*

```
$fichier=$ARGV[0]; # fichier a traiter par le parser
warn $fichier;
$output=$fichier."_OUTPUT";
chomp($fichier); # Suppression des \n incongrus
@cstemp1 = split(/\//,$fichier);
@cstemp2 = split(/_/,$cstemp1[$#cstemp1]);
$cs = $cstemp2[1];
$ip = $cstemp2[2];
my ($etat, $ifname, $myip); # Variables a la chaine

# Ouverture des flux d'entrée et de sortie
open(DATA,$fichier) || die ("Erreur d'ouverture de $fichier\n") ;
close(DATA);
```

Now what happens when executing ?

```
perl executeParsers.pl
OBS,9 Cegetel,Altitude
sh ip int
shipint
parser1.pl

prefixe trouve shipint
j'ai trouve les fichiers suivant : /tech/gtr/scripts/osm/environnement_qualif/scan-rh2/working-dir/shipint_952923S1_<ip>

le fichier numero 0 est : /tech/gtr/scripts/osm/environnement_qualif/scan-rh2/working-dir/shipint_952923S1_<ip>
fichier traite : /tech/gtr/scripts/osm/environnement_qualif/scan-rh2/working-dir/shipint_952923S1_<ip>
Warning: something's wrong at /tech/gtr/scripts/osm/environnement_qualif/scan-rh2/parsers/parser1.pl line 7.
Erreur d'ouverture de
sh: line 1: /tech/gtr/scripts/osm/environnement_qualif/scan-rh2/working-dir/shipint_952923S1_<ip>: Permission denied
OBS,9 Cegetel,Altitude
sh int status
shintstatus
parser2.pl
prefixe trouve shintstatus
j'ai trouve les fichiers suivant :
```

Now, if i'm deleting the second line from my *ssh.conf* file, it's working.
I guess there's something wrong with the end of line.

Comment: Seems like `$fichier` is empty.

Comment: what is the permission to the actual file besides the working-dir?

Comment: Since you've not shown us the code in parser1.pl that leads up to the error message, it is hard to know what is going wrong.  I recommend creating an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names (and links) for the same idea.  The MCVE will have two small scripts — maybe 10 lines each, possibly shorter.  Note that there are ways to specify the Perl executable, such as `$^X` or `$EXECUTABLE_NAME` if you're using `use English '-no_match_vars';`.

Comment: Consider using: `system("/usr/bin/perl", "$DIR/parsers/$parsername", "$fichier");` using a list of arguments to `system`.  This avoids executing the shell at all.  The error message is curious, apparently identifying what you think is the file name as if it was the script name.  What exactly do you have in the shebang line of the `parser1.pl`?

Comment: Did you try using the Perl debugger before posting the question? Examining key variables at important points of the program can help a lot. Also converting to English might widen the audience significantly.

Answer (score 1):

`$fichier` likely doesn't contain what you think it does. Use `warn $fichier;` to find out what it contains before use. Also, use the three argument open and the `$!` variable to tell you why things failed:

```
open(my $fh, "<", "input.txt")
or die "cannot open < input.txt: $!";
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question and should be a comment

Comment: I printed the argument before beeing sent to "parser1.pl", there is a valid argument...

Answer (score 0):

Another Carriage return mistake.

When printing the full output of vars we have :

```
prefixe trouve shipint
operateurs : OBS,9 Cegetel,Altitude
commandes : sh ip int
parser name : parser1.pl

j'ai trouve les fichiers suivant : /tech/gtr/scripts/osm/environnement_qualif/scan-rh2/working-dir/shipint_952923S1_126.110.101.250

le fichier numero 0 est : /tech/gtr/scripts/osm/environnement_qualif/scan-rh2/working-dir/shipint_952923S1_126.110.101.250
```

That means there's a carriage return on the $parsername that must be deleted with

```
$parsername =~ s/\s+\z// ;
```